# How to write pyaudio output into audio file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, pyaudio

I currently have the following code, which produces a sine wave of varying frequencies using the `pyaudio` module:

```
import pyaudio
import numpy as np

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

volume = 0.5
fs = 44100
duration = 1

f = 440

samples = (np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.arange(fs * duration) * f / 
fs)).astype(np.float32).tobytes()

stream = p.open(format = pyaudio.paFloat32,
                channels = 1,
                rate = fs,
                output = True)

stream.write(samples)
```

However, instead of playing the sound, is there any way to make it so that the sound is written into an audio file?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I am getting noisy files while saving the paFloat32 in .wav

Comment: @Matias sorry for the lack of response on my behalf. The answer I just wrote produced a file with no noise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `scipy.io.wavfile.write` as suggested by @h lee produced the desired results:

```
import numpy
from scipy.io.wavfile import write

volume = 1
sample_rate = 44100
duration = 10
frequency = 1000

samples = (numpy.sin(2 * numpy.pi * numpy.arange(sample_rate * duration)
     * frequency / sample_rate)).astype(numpy.float32)

write('test.wav', sample_rate, samples)
```

Another example can be found on the documentation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.write.html

Answer (score 2):

Add this code at the top of your code.

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import write
```

Also, add this code at the bottom of your code.
This worked for me.

```
scaled = numpy.int16(s/numpy.max(numpy.abs(s)) * 32767)
write('test.wav', 44100, scaled)
```

Answer (score 1):

Handle your audio input as a numpy array like I did [here in the second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22101023/how-to-handle-in-data-in-pyaudio-callback-mode/61584258#61584258), but instead of just processing the frames and sending the data back to PyAudio, save each frame in a new `output_array`. Then when the processing is done you can use that `output_array` to write it to .wav or .mp3 file.

If you do that, however, the sound would still play. If you don't want to play the sound you have two options, either using the blocking mode or, if you wanna stick with the non blocking mode and the callbacks, do the following:

- Erase `output=True` so that it is `False` as default.
- Add a `input=True` parameter.
- In your callback do not return `ret_data`, instead return `None`.
- Keep count of the frames you've processed so that when you're done you return `paComplete` as second value of the returned tuple.